# How to save a spacy model with UMLSEntityLinker on disk and load that as well?

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition, allennlp

I have below code and I want to save this exact model on the disk and load that in the code. So that I can prevent resource exhaustion.

```
import scispacy
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from scispacy.abbreviation import AbbreviationDetector
from scispacy.umls_linking import UmlsEntityLinker
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_sm-0.2.5/en_core_sci_sm/en_core_sci_sm-0.2.5')

linker = UmlsEntityLinker(resolve_abbreviations=True)

nlp.add_pipe(linker)
```